# Simple image filter using GLSL Fragment Shader

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am starting with OpenGL ES 2 and I am trying to build a very simple app where I have a static image and a button that applies an Instagram-like photo filter using a GLSL fragment shader to that image.

I've been reading a lot of tutorials, where the different algorithms are well explained, but I just don't know how the input has to be made. What I mean is, where do I "pass the image as a parameter" in order to get its bitmap or pixel buffer so I can manipulate it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good sample app in the Android SDK named "HelloEffects" that does this.  The image is loaded as a "texture" via the function glTexImage2D() or GLUtils.texImage2D().

I think this article will help:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's all about binding your texture and pass its ID as a uniform that points to a so-called *GLSL texture sampler* ([Sampler_(GLSL) wiki link](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Binding_textures_to_samplers)). Then, the magic glsl command is `texture2D()`.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program,"texsampler"),0);
```

where `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTUREi);` activates the specified *i* slot and `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);` binds textureID to that slot.
The *0* in `glUniform1i()` actually equals *i*.
Don't forget to un-bind everything after using it.

Example vertex shader:

```
varying vec2 texcoord;

void main() {

    gl_Position=gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
    texcoord=gl_Vertex.xy; // or whatever you need to pass texture coordinates
}
```

Example fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 texcoord;
uniform sampler2D texsampler;

void main() {

    gl_FragColor=vec4(texture2D(texsampler,texcoord).rgb,1.0);

}
```